# How to use 'Local' modules in 'GoLang'

Tags: go

I'm building an application using a 'Micro Service' architecture.
This means that I have different applications.
The truth is that some logic is in a 'shared' library.

See the following directory structure:

```
ROOT/
├── Service 1/
│   ├── src
│   ├──── app.go
├── Service 2/
│   ├── src
│   ├──── app.go
└── Lib/
    ├── Lib 1
    │   ├── src
    │   ├──── app.go
```

**Service 1**, **Service 2**, and **Lib 1**, are all initialized with the `go mod` command.

For **Service 1**, this resulted in a `go.mod` file with the following contents.

```
module github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/services/serviceOne
```

For **Service 2**, this resulted in a `go.mod` file with the following contents.

```
module github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/services/serviceTwo
```

For **Lib 1**, this resulted in a `go.mod` file with the following contents.

```
module github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/lib/libOne
```

The `import` statements of **Service 1** contains a reference to the **Lib 1**

```
import (
    "github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/lib/libOne"
)
```

However, when I try to build the application, the following output is showed:

```
go: finding github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/lib/libOne latest
go: finding github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/lib latest
go: finding github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics latest
build github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/services/serviceOne/src: 
cannot find module for path github.com/kevin-de-coninck/datalytics/lib/libOne
```

How can I resolve this issue so that i can use my **LibOne** package without making it public or whithout copying it across all the services?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling around, I have found my answer.
It seems that the 'go.mod' and 'go.sum' file(s) should be placed in the 'src' directory.
After doing that, the application can be build and executed.